# Трансляция на сайт с помощью OBS

Tags: трансляция

Весь интернет перерыл, ничего полезного не нашёл. Хочу понять, как можно БЕЗ СТОРОННИХ СЕРВИСОВ сделать трансляцию на сайте? А именно передать видеопоток из OBS в плеер на сайте. В интернете советуют только сторонний сервисы трансляций, но в моём случае не подойдут.
Подскажите, как можно это сделать и желательно с примерами кода или ссылками.
Спасибо!

Comment: А почему не подойдут-то?

Comment: Потому что мне нужно ограничить пользователю возможность переходить на оригинальную страницу. Надо чтобы он мог смотреть мою трансляцию только на моей странице, а не на странице сервиса. Пустые div не вариант

Comment: Например, установить rtmp-сервер на какой-нибудь машине (например, на той же, где установлен сайт), транслировать с OBS на этот rtmp-сервер, с помощью ffmpeg забирать поток с rtmp-сервера и нарезать на hls или mpeg-dash файлы и через http отдавать эти файлы плееру (hls.js или dash.js соответственно)

Comment: Классно, но я вообще в теме трансляций не шарю. Какие rtmp сервера бывают и можете посоветовать?